# firebase database - adding the current server-side timestamp as a key

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

using firebase functions (NODE) I would like to create a timestamp base node to save my data using timestamp as key name:

EX:

```
WATERLEVEL
    16934723478:1
    16934723482:2
    16934723483:50
```

I'm trying to using this code without success.

```
    const timest = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP ;

    let waterData = {};
    waterData[timest] = req.body.WATERLEVEL;

    rtdb.child("SENSOR").child(req.body.SERIAL).child("LEVEL").update(waterData);
```

Can somebody drive me to the right approach ?  could a variable been used as key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` variable is not actually a timestamp, but an instruction to the database to write the current timestamp. There is no way in the Firebase Realtime Database to write this value into a key; it can only be used in values.

If you want to write the current server-side timestamp from Cloud Functions as a key, use:

```
const timest = Date.now();
```

Comment: THANKS! you right!  I discovered in fact it expose an object. in a precedent usage, using it as a child value it worked , probably firebase recognise it. btw I solved :)